# umake - Unity3d installation failed

Tags: games, development

when I install Unity3d via umake utility i get following error message.

```
    Choose installation path: /home/unknown/tools/games/unity3d
Downloading and installing requirements                                        |
ERROR: installArchives() failed
Subprocess output: E:Reverse conflicts early remove for package 'libglapi-mesa:amd64' failed
```

Does anyone know how can I resolve this? I will be very happy if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to install Unity3d on Ubuntu (tested on 14.04LTS and 15):
download Unity3d:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/08/unity3d-linux-build
(the blue button `Download Unity 3D Editor for Ubuntu`)

then do these following line:

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop xterm
sudo dpkg -i unity-editor*.deb
sudo chmod 4755 /opt/Unity/Editor/chrome-sandbox
```

and normaly you have it !